# Display Sound waves for Audio recording in Android

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

How can we display sound waves as displayed in below image..

When user speaks, The yellow bars will animate based on user's volume.

[image]

Please guide me.. Is there any reference link available? Is there any sample tutorial available?

Same Question in iPhone. but i wants to it in Android.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `MediaRecorder` for recording audio you can periodically request amplitude with [MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude%28%29). Then you can create [ClipDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) from bars bitmap and use amplitude to set desired level.